# Command mvn spring-boot:run cause ClassNotFound Exception with JPA Metamodel

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I'm having a spring boot application using JPA Metamodel.
The thing is, when I run `mvn spring-boot:run` command, it cause a failure build with a `ClassNotFound` exception happens with JPA Metamodel class

````
```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LSingularAttribute;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.thanglequoc.SpringRollApplication.main(SpringRollApplication.java:10)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LSingularAttribute;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.registerAttribute(MetadataContext.java:421)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.registerAttributes(MetadataContext.java:381)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.populateStaticMetamodel(MetadataContext.java:358)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:890)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SingularAttribute
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 39 more
```
````

My **pom.xml**

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.thanglequoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-roll-company</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-roll-company</name>
    <description>Spring Roll Company is a goofy and playful company, built on Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.thanglequoc.SpringRollApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

```
````

I belived the metamodel set up is alright, because when I run the spring boot with **Eclipse** (with Spring Boot plugin installed), using `Run As -> Spring Boot App`, it ran successfully without any error. I suspects there is a difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` command and Eclipse Spring Boot Application run procedure, but haven't yet figured out.

That JPA Metamodel ClassNotFound exception also happen when I run `mvn test` using Maven SureFire plugin, I have to run `mvn test-compile test` to make thing works.

Comment: maybe your eclipse uses its embedded maven. the  difference can be in setting.xml configuration (see mirrors and proxies)

Comment: try adding `repackage` execution to `spring-boot-maven-plugin`